# How to decalre array of enums?

Tags: c, enums

I have the following enum:

```
enum {
       ClientRx,
       ClientTx,

       Server1Rx,
       Server1Tx,
       Server1RxDropped,
       Server1TxDropped,

       Server2Rx,
       Server2Tx,
       Server2RxDropped,
       Server2TxDropped,

       Server3Rx,
       Server3Tx,
       Server3RxDropped,
       Server3TxDropped,

       Server4Rx,
       Server4Tx,
       Server4RxDropped,
       Server4TxDropped,

       MaxVal
};
```

Is there a way to create an array of server enums that will fit in original enum to make this code more generic? (e.g. If I want to extend number of server counters to 100...)

Something in the form:

```
typedef enum {
           ServerRx,
           ServerTx,
           ServerRxDropped,
           ServerTxDropped
}eServerCounters;

eServerCounters ServerCountersArray[4];
enum {
       ClientRx,
       ClientTx,

       ServerCountersArray,

       MaxVal
};
```

Get enum value:

```
ServerCountersArray[2].ServerRx
```

Comment: I think you are confused about what an `enum` is.

Comment: These are just indexes... real counters are stored in an array.

Comment: So if I want to extend this enum to support 100 server counter indexes... I need to add 100 * 4 entries..? is there no other way?

Comment: It seems like you are merely looking for an array of typedef:ed enum objects. Or possibly just a big bitfield.

Comment: Anyway, this is a so-called "XY problem". You have a problem and made a solution which you think solves the problem. However, that solution is not correct - rather than asking of how to fix the solution, you should ask how to solve the original problem that the code is actually supposed to fix.

Comment: I dare say that when you have a label `Server3RxDropped`, your data model is broken.

Comment: @Cheatah what do you mean?

Comment: That you need to reconsider how you store and access the data. Say if I want to programmatically iterate over all server Rx counters, how am I going to do that?

Comment: @Cheatah What are some good alternatives to that? I have an integer array that stores counters in indexes of this enum. There are other counters also (not just server counters). All counter names (and indexes for access) are this enum.

Comment: If you have any control over how the counters are stored, fix that. If you don't, then at least create a more user friendly API around it. Like, write a function that accepts a queue number parameter, or byte shift and mask the queue number with the sub-counter.

Comment: @Cheatah I'm not sure I have control over how counter values are actually stored. I'm indeed trying to make this more user friendly. I just thought I can segment this huge flat enum somehow to ease this indexing maintenance.

Answer (score 2):

In C enumerations are a way to create symbolic integer constants in the global namespace.

With your definition

```
eServerCounters ServerCountersArray[4];
```

you create an array of four elements. *Each* element can have any of the values from the `eServerCounters` enumeration.

For example you can check if the third element is equal to `ServerRx` like

```
if (ServerCountersArray[2] == ServerRx) ...
```

Of perhaps you need to `swtich` between the different values:

```
switch (ServerCountersArray[i])
{
case ServerRx:
    // Do something here...
    break;
case ServerTx:
    // Do something here...
    break;

case ServerRxDropped:
    // Do something here...
    break;

case ServerTxDropped:
    // Do something here...
    break;
}
```

---

Thinking a little more about the code and the comments by Cheatah, it seems like what you might need is an array of structures:

```
struct counter
{
    unsigned rx;
    unsigned tx;
    unsigned rx_dropped;
    unsigned tx_dropped;
};

struct counter counters[4];
```

Now you can access the counter for a specific  "channel" from the array, like e.g.

```
for (unsigned ch = 0; ch < 4; ++ch)
{
    printf("Channel %u:\n", ch + 1);
    printf("    Rx: %u (dropped %u)\n", counters[ch].rx, counters[ch].rx_dropped);
    printf("    Tx: %u (dropped %u)\n", counters[ch].tx, counters[ch].tx_dropped);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate large enun definition

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int nservers =  -1;

    printf("typedef enum {\n"
           "\t\tClientRx,\n"
           "\t\tClientTx,\n\n");
    if(argc > 1 && sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &nservers) == 1 && nservers != -1)
    {
        for(int server = 1; server <= nservers; server++)
        {
            printf("\t\tServer%dRx,\n" , server);
            printf("\t\tServer%dTx,\n" , server);
            printf("\t\tServer%dRDropped,\n" , server);
            printf("\t\tServer%dTxDropped,\n\n" , server);
        }
    }

    printf("} serverEnumType;\n");
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/sTGezaer7